# My App cannot connected when running expo start --dev-client

Tags: react-native, expo

I built my app on a physical device using Xcode. After that, the launcher screen appeared. Then, I ran the command 'npx expo start --dev-client'. After scanning the QR code, Safari opened with the message 'Safari cannot open the page because it could not connect to the server' with this URL: http://localhost:8081.

When I hit 'r' to reload, it says 'warn: No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.'

My computer and device are connected to the same Wi-Fi.

It works fine on the iOS simulator

Any help ?

**Package versions**

```
"@expo-google-fonts/baskervville": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo-google-fonts/mulish": "^0.2.3",
    "@kanelloc/react-native-animated-header-scroll-view": "^0.12.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "6.9.7",
    "@tamagui/animations-reanimated": "1.5.19",
    "@tamagui/font-inter": "1.5.19",
    "@tamagui/lucide-icons": "1.5.19",
    "@tamagui/shorthands": "1.5.19",
    "@tamagui/theme-base": "1.5.19",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "expo": "~47.0.12",
    "expo-av": "~13.0.3",
    "expo-dev-client": "2.1.6",
    "expo-font": "11.0.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "12.0.1",
    "expo-speech": "~11.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.17.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "expo-updates": "~0.15.6",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.9.0",
    "react-native-lightbox-v2": "^0.9.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "2.14.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.18.2",
    "react-native-shadow-2": "^7.0.6",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-timeline-flatlist": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.18.10",
    "tamagui": "1.5.19",
    "yarn": "^1.22.19"
```

**Expo Workflow**: bare

**Environment**

```
 System:
      OS: macOS 12.5.1
      Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 19.8.1 - /opt/homebrew/bin/node
      Yarn: 3.2.0 - ~/Documents/dev/maison-des-geants/node_modules/.bin/yarn
      npm: 8.19.4 - ~/Documents/dev/maison-des-geants/node_modules/.bin/npm
    Managers:
      CocoaPods: 1.12.0 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: DriverKit 22.2, iOS 16.2, macOS 13.1, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 2022.1 AI-221.6008.13.2211.9619390
      Xcode: 14.2/14C18 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      expo: ~47.0.12 => 47.0.13 
      react: 18.1.0 => 18.1.0 
      react-dom: 18.1.0 => 18.1.0 
      react-native: 0.70.5 => 0.70.5 
      react-native-web: 0.18.10 => 0.18.10 
    Expo Workflow: bare
```

Answer (score 1):

I was running the wrong command, so I ran expo start instead and it worked.